# what is the accuracy difference between TransformationValidationEuclidean and getFitnessScore() of registration module?

Tags: point-cloud-library

I am working on localisation monitor. I need a function to validate a transform. I found two functions: getFitnessScore and TransformationValidationEuclidean. I wanted to know which function is resilient when it comes to transformation validation.

Comment: What do you mean with "resilient" exactly? Have you looked at the source code of the two functions to understand what they do?